# Django foreign key display values in detail view

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a main DB table Radni_nalozi (Work Orders) to which I am attaching Stavke (items) by a foreign key.
When I go to see details about a specific Work Order I also want to display all the items that are connected to that Work Order by a foreign key.

I tried many different approaches and it seems that I just can't figure it out on my own.
I am attaching the code below. In an HTML template, I can only fetch details about specific work orders but not the items.

[image: models.py]

[image: views.py]

[image: template html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using ForeignKey in django, you can access all rows that are in relationship with one row using "related_name" parameter.To get all the items that are connected to that Work Order(id=1) by a foreign key.

   ```
   radni_nalozi_obj = Radni_nalozi.objects.get(id=1)
   radni_nalozi_obj.stavka       //we are using related_name that is mentioned in "Stavke" model for "Artikl" foreignkkey.
   ```
2. In your detail view, you may have to modify the context object before returning.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `get_context_data` to your detail view in order to get the object and fetch all items related to that obj. Basically, this method replaces the default `context` provided by the `DetailView`, so you have to also include the object itself.

```py
class RadniDetailView(DetailView):

    # ..... remain code ......

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(RadniDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        radni_obj = self.object # this contain the object that the view is operating upon
        context['object'] = radni_obj # don't forget this also

        # Get all items/Stavke related to the work order/Radni_nalozi
        context['items'] = Stavke.objects.filter(Rn=radni_obj)
        return context
```

inside HTML you can display all items like so

```
{% for item in items %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```